# How do I solve for the argument in this two equation system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that a row vector $X$ and a column vector $a$, both with the same 1 dimensional length $N$, and given that constant $K$ is defined as

$K={{a_1}{X_1}}+{{a_2}{X_2}}+{{a_3}{X_3}}+...+{{a_N}{X_N}}$

and that for any given element $i$

$\dfrac{a_i}{X_i}=constant$

How do I solve for all values of X?

Comment: What does the condition tell you about the relationship between the two vectors?

Comment: $\frac{a_i}{X_i}=...$ How come you are dividing vectors? Did you mean that the corresponding elements of $i^{th}$ row and column are proportional?

Comment: This is basically a mathematical representation of an engineering problem I have which is akin to a statically indeterminate structure, but simplified. 

Essentially, this is like a bracket with N fasteners holding it to a support structure, where 'a' is the distance from the pivot point, and X is the magnitude of the axial force at each fastener.

Because the bending load applied to the bracket will be equal to the sum of the resisting moments for every fastener, that's what the first equation tells us.

And the second equation comes from the law of similar triangles.